# How should this question be edited

Tags: discussion

This question [How do I run a .sh or .command file in Terminal](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/235128/237) has just come up on the front page.

The title says How do I run a .sh or .command file in Terminal

The question however asks How do I run a .sh or .command file from Finder

I think the title needs to be edited and normally I would do so

However given the questions's popularity and the most upvoted answers answer the title and not the question and also the OP self answered

What should be done?

Given the mess I could justify closing as needs more clarity

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the best edit is no edit when it’s not clear or the question has aged a year or more.

I can’t see anything making it better and attempts to fix the problem make it worse. Closing a question that doesn’t need more answers is always a good option. The body seems to me to explain that since the person doesn’t know how to click in Finder, they want to learn the basics of shell execution. Perhaps copying the title to the body would help, but I see no reason to do just that. I didn’t when I fixed the tags a few years back.

You can see the very light touch two moderators used to edit it in the past:

- https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/235128/revisions

Comment: I think the mods missed a chance to edit the title on the day it was asked :) As for closing - like the mods I can close it on my own but in this case I would like some consensus first